# mongodb get/post hangs (or is so slow it seems hung)

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I continue apace in banging my head on mongoose/mongodb/express/node app. Today, it's the ultimate slowness cage match. We're talking snails would be ashamed to go this slow. I've looked through the mongodb answers that touch on slowness/hanging, but the examples are all either massive or really complex compared to my case. Which probably means I'm missing something really simple that'd fix it. I just don't know what.

I have three collections, none of which have more than 100 entries. The biggest collection has a little over 200 variables. I get the values from the user via basic html form and submit it all as a put:

```
    router.route('/items/:user_id/:item_id')
        // update 
        .put(function(req, res) {
            var item = req.body;
            var id = req.params.item_id;
            Items.update({_id: id}, item, function(err, item) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
            });
        })
```

Once that's completed, I reroute the user to a page that shows the entire file, and populate it via a get that continues immediately after the above:

```
        // view
        .get(function(req, res) {
            var id = req.params.item_id;
            Items.find({'_id':id},function(err, item) {
                if (err)
                    res.json(err);
                res.send(item);
            });
        })
```

But instead of being all nice and speedy like you'd expect with a miniature database and teeny updates (relatively speaking), it hangs abominably. When I look at the Network tab in Chrome, it says the PUT is stalled, and doesn't even indicate ever completing. The GET that follows immediately also hangs, for about 20s, and then (finally!) the page populates with the updated info.

(Well, sometimes. There have been a number of times it seems like the PUT just never went through, so the GET shows the unchanged info. Argh.)

I did come across a tutorial that said res.send contains a res.end, so you don't have to do that twice, but the only res.send is if there's an error. I tried adding res.end() as the last bit in each, but then I got errors saying I couldn't write to headers after they were sent. But my general suspicion is that I need something to tell the PUT that it's done.

Is the problem that the PUT doesn't have a formal end, and if so, what do I add to make it not error and just end? Or should I do a single res.end() after both the PUT and the GET, at the bottom of the router.route call? Or should I break the two into separate router.route calls? Or is there a limit on how many items I should be tracking in a model? I have no idea, so I throw myself on the mercy of ye gods of mongo/mongoose.

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were o the right track about the PUT command not terminating. What is happening is that the code is handling the put, and after it is successful it runs the callback. But that only has code in it to handle an error, so that's why you are seeing the hang.

```
router.route('/items/:user_id/:item_id')
    // update 
    .put(function(req, res) {
        var item = req.body;
        var id = req.params.item_id;
        Items.update({_id: id}, item, function(err, item) {
            if (err)
                **return** res.send(err);
            **res.status(200).end();**
        });
    })
```

On the get side you are certainly asking fro trouble with the current code as you have two send's one after the other

```
    .get(function(req, res) {
        var id = req.params.item_id;
        Items.find({'_id':id},function(err, item) {
            if (err)
                **return** res.json(err);
            res.send(item);
        });
    })
```

Comment: So in general, keep error replies as res.json, and always close each one out with a res.send? It does treat the PUT and GET as separate, right, so they should each get their own end (res.send)?

Comment: made the changes and WAH THE SPEED IT IS AMAZING. thank you!!

Comment: it does not matter how you return errors, but you need the return so that the code stops after sending the erorr, and you must return success too